# Find and delete particular text from label XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, text, label

Ok so I am looking for a piece of code that will take text out of label. Before I tell you , I looked all around internet.

Example

Label's text : `Hi I am asking for help.`

Ok so what I want the program to do is when I hit a button to remove part of the text like this.

From : `Hi I am asking for help`  to   `Hi I asking for help`

deleting the word 'am'.

Don't tell me to do any manual changing like, `label.text = @"Hi I asking for help".`
Because the value I am trying to change is static and it is an RSS Reader.

Summary :

I want to remove particular text from label, example taking a word out from the middle of the label and re-displaying the new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *myString = @"Hi I am asking for help.";
NSString *updated = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" am" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",updated);
```

output will be:- Hi I asking for help.

Comment: @Xcoder the answer that you have accepted will remove "am" with empty space.But the sentence will have addition space bw i and asking ie         "Hi i__asking for help"

Comment: Plus one more question do you know how to do this,  (if a label includes this text) then { }

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: umm I will link u up to another question that I made

Comment: i have given a solution,checkout if tats d one u want

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

...to get a new string with a substring replaced (See NSString documentation for others)

Example:

```
NSString *str = @"Hi I am asking for help.";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"am"
                                     withString:@""];
```